# .NET Printing - How to determine if text fits within a specified rectangle

Tags: .net

I need to be able to determine if user entered text fits within the bounds of a section of a printed page with a predefined report layout, ex. section A: is leaves space for a 2x3 inch rectangle to contain text, but can contain all the text from War and Peace. If text does not fit within a given rectangle, I need to print another page and continue printing any text that overflowed the previously printed page's section.

The application is written in VB 2010 Express, but examples in C# are welcome.

TIA

Comment: And this is GDI+ (PrintDocument) based printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the MeasureString and MeasureCharacterRanges function on the Graphics class.

Comment: Right. The MeasureString can be used to accomplish this. Here's an example:

Comment: No, hears a starting point.  If intellisense doesn't make the use of that method completely obvious, then a half-second Google search will.  Do your own work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I hope others will find useful for determining the amount of text 
that will fit in a give area:

```
Public Function GetTextThatFitsLength( _
        ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs, _
        Text As String, _
        ByVal Width As Integer, _
        ByVal Height As Integer, _
        ByVal Font As Font, _
        Optional ByRef LinesFilled As Integer = 0) As Integer
        ' returns the number of charaters that fit into the specified area 
        ' optionally returns the number of lines that fit into the area
        Dim LayoutArea As New SizeF
        With LayoutArea
            .Width = Width
            .Height = Height
        End With
        Dim StringFormat As New StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault)
        With StringFormat
            .Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
            .Trimming = StringTrimming.Word
        End With
        Dim CharactersFitted As Integer
        e.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font, LayoutArea, StringFormat, CharactersFitted, LinesFilled)
        Return CharactersFitted
    End Function
```